# In Python, is there anyway you can make non-terminating float (fraction) into a string without chaing its state?

Tags: python, math, floating-point, integer, fractions

Is there any way you can make non-terminating float (non-terminating fraction) into string while preserving its format (no decimal. i.e. 1.666667)? For instance, I want 7/6 to be '7/6'. Assuming the non-terminating float is **unknown**, and the code should work with any number. You are allowed to import, however, you can't create a new file. I've attempted multiple times, but I could only work this out using file. 
We will start like this →
`a = 7/6`

Comment: What is the number to begin with? Literally something like `a = 7/6`, so `a` is a `float`? What's with the restriction about files?

Comment: Yes, you are right like a =7/6. Creating a new file isn't efficient and not a great solution so I excluded.

Comment: Not sure how creating a new file would be relevant in any way to begin with… Anyway, your float doesn't contain the information "7/6", it's just `1.666667`. Could have been `14/12` to begin with, or any other number. You'll need to use a different data type than a float to "preserve the format".

Comment: Yes sorry, I changed the title. What do you mean by different data type?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Cann't you simply print `str("7/6")`? I guess the problem here is more to detect such "irrational" cases, which may not be so simple as you are dealing with binary representation in computers... E.g. have a look [here](https://0.30000000000000004.com/).

Comment: Hi s.k. we are assuming that a = 7/6 so str(7/6) will not work

Comment: I'm afraid the question is unclear. What's a "non-terminating float"? Are you talking about a Python object of type `float`? And what do you mean by "unknown": how does one do anything with an unknown piece of information?  Could you edit your question to give some examples of the behaviour you want? If you're somehow hoping to reverse an integer division (recover the numerator and denominator from the resulting float), then that's not going to be possible in general: different fractions will give the same float.

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

As stated by [Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60785632/6630397), you can use the [Fraction](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/fractions.html) module.

Especially look at its `limit_denominator()` method.

> Finds and returns the closest Fraction to self that has denominator at
>   most max_denominator. This method is useful for finding rational
>   approximations to a given floating-point number

For example in your case:

```
from fractions import Fraction
a = 7/6.
print(Fraction(a).limit_denominator(max_denominator=100000))
7/6
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator
and: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fraction-module-python/

### EDIT

If your number has to many places after the decimal, you may then think about rounding it, e.g.:

```
from math import log10
from fractions import Fraction
a = 7/6.
rounding_factor = 100000
a = round(a, int(log10(rounding_factor)))
print(Fraction(a).limit_denominator(max_denominator=int(rounding_factor/10)))
7/6
```

Turned into a function, it may look like this (try to play around with it):

```
def transform_decimal_to_fraction(a, rounding_factor=100000):
    """Return a string representing the input number a as a fraction.
    Parameters:
    ----------
    a : float
        The variable on which to perform the transformation to a fraction string.
    rounding_factor : int
        The rounding factor to use. This factor is transforme to its log10 to
        cut the input variable a to a limited number of digits after the decimal
        point. It is also used, dived by 10 to adapt to the latter, as the 
        max_denominator used by Fraction.
        Default value = 100000.

    Returns:
    -------
    retval : str
        A string representing the input variable as a fraction.
    """
    from math import log10
    from fractions import Fraction
    a = round(a, int(log10(rounding_factor)))
    b = (Fraction(a).limit_denominator(max_denominator=int(rounding_factor/10)))
    retval = str(b)

    return(retval)
```

#### Notice

Of course, the range of numbers to which this function applies is dependent of both your inputs.

Comment: Hi, s.k thanks for your answer. We are assuming the non-terminating fraction is unknown. Therefore, there may be a fraction that exceeds 100000.

Comment: @Sonav: Then no, there's no way to do what you want. By the time you represent the fraction as a float, you've already lost information. For example, `102334155 / 165580141` and `39088169 / 63245986` give exactly the same float on a typical machine, but they're not equivalent as fractions.

Comment: If it exceeds the `max_denominator` you can tweak the function (see edit) by cutting your input floating number to a fixed amount of digits, assuming `1.666667` is equivalent to `1.666666666667` then. This of course has its limitations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in [`Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) class:

```py
from fractions import Fraction
f = Fraction(7, 6)
```

Comment: Hi Mureinik, thanks for the answer. unfortunately, that's not what I want. We can't assume the number the user gives. Fraction(7/6) will not work, but Fraction('7/6') works. And we are trying to make a non-terminating fraction into a string while preserving its format.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [mpmath's](http://mpmath.org/) [`identify()`](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/identification.html) function. Mpmath is Python's multi precision library.

`identify()` works for fractions as well as square roots, logarithms, exponentials as well as some mathematical constants and linear combinations thereof.

As others have noted, the process is very prune to rounding and precision. You might need to experiment with your exact use case.

Note that often the number you want to represent as fraction is the result of some calculations and accumulates rounding errors. To cope with these errors, `identify()` can have a tolerance as argument.

An example:

```py
from mpmath import mp
print(mp.identify(mp.phi))  # ---> ((1+sqrt(5))/2)
print(mp.identify(1.666667, tol=1e-6))  # ---> (5/3)
```

The mathematics of converting a float to a fraction is quite straightforward. A [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) is calculated until some tolerance is reached, after which it's continued fraction is rewritten as a normal fraction.